# state matrix Xk on kalman filter does not match with the size of the ecuation

Tags: node.js, math, matrix, linear-algebra, kalman-filter

I'm facing issues when I try to update the estimation of the state matrix. because the sizes does not match.

I'm reading this excellent [documentation](https://www.kalmanfilter.net/multiSummary.html) to learn about de theory behind the kalman filter.

In summary the sizes of the matrix are:

**x = state vector => mx*1**

**z = output vector => mz*1**

**F = state transition matrix => mx*nx**

**P = estimated uncertainty matrix => mx*nx**

**Q = process noise uncertanty matrix => mx*nx**

**R = Measurement uncertainty matrix => mz*nz**

**H = Observation matrix => mz*nx**

**K = Kalman Gain => mx*nz**

In my implementation, I am using the filter for tracking an object. My state vector looks like this.

```
x=[px,vx,ax,py,vy,ay];
```

The output vector

```
z=[px,py]
```

The state transition matrix

```
F = [
    [ 1, 1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

the variance-covariance matrix

```
P = [
    [ 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

The process noise

```
Q = [
    [ 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]]
```

The measurement noise

```
R = [
    [3, 0],
    [0, 2]]
```

The observation matrix

```
H = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I did this because i want only the position of the result. (x,y)

Running the acuations...

**1. Time Update**

```
1. Extrapolate the state
Xk^=F*Xk_1
```

No problem here, no control input because i'm just reading the values, the result is **mx*1**

```
2. Extrapolate the uncertainty
Pk=F*Pk_1*FT + Q
```

No Problem here, the sizes are correct, and the result is like the theory says, **mx*nx**

**2. Measurement Update**
    1. Computing the kalman gain

```
K=Pk*HT*(H*Pk*HT+ R)^-1
```

No problem here, the result is like the theory, **mx*nz**.

```
2.Update the estimate uncertainty
Pk'= Pk- K*H*Pk
```

No problem here, the result is like the expected, **mx*nx**.

```
3.Update the estimate (state), with measurement.
Xk=Xk^ + K*(z-H*Xk^)
```

And finally this is the problem, what i am doing is compute first `K*(z-H*Xk^)`. it results in a matrix with **mz*nz**, in other words (2x2) size, but the `Xk^` vector has this size **mx*1**. So, when I try to add this both matrix, it results in an error.

How can I solve this? I dont know, I can't see what i'm missing.

i'm using nodejs to run this. But i have the step by step in spread sheet in excel.

Answer (score 1):

(z - H*Xk^) is also called innovation , and it should have dimensions nz x 1. I suspect this is where the problem occurs.

You can define

z^ = H*Xk^, and its dimensions should also be nz x 1

My guess is that you have multiple stacked measurements in the z variable, i.e., instead of z being nz*1 , it actually is nz x Nz, where nz is the dimensionality of a measurement, and Nz the number of measurements. In that case you can either perform sequential single measurement updates after separating the z^ matrix into nz x 1 vectors, but that would mean you would have to be able to calculate a prediction for every measurement in the stacked measurements vector.

Answer (score 0):

If we split

```
Xk^ + K*(z-H*Xk^)
```

into steps:

```
H*Xk^ is mz*nx by nx*1 so is mz*1
z - H*Xk^ is mz*1 - mz*1 so is mz*1
K*(z-H*Xk^) is mx*nz by mz*1 so is mx*1
```

(BTW I find your use of e.g. mx and nx confusing. These numbers must be equal (because P is square).)